# How to write PL/SQL that determines the SQL DML Operation being performed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'd like to write a PL/SQL procedure that accepts a SQL string as a parameter and determines whether the SQL statement is a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement or OTHER, if none of the above (if it were a DDL statement, for example). Or perhaps it could return DDL and there might still be a need for a "OTHER."

In any event, because the SQL can, of course, get very complex and vary widely, I expect that the  only way to do is to make use of the SQL parsing engine that Oracle has built into it, if this functionality  is exposed. I've been looking though the  [DBMS_SQL library](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C96D5BAA-29A9-4AB5-A69E-E31228ECC9E9) for a way but I thought I would see if anyone else has experience in this area.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  It seems like you could simply eliminate leading whitespace and see if the statement begins with `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or something else.  My guess is that you actually want to do something more involved than this question covers so this simplistic approach isn't helpful

Comment: I had the same thought as @JustinCave. What is the intent behind this procedure? What problem is it trying to solve? This feels a bit like a roundabout way of doing something that Oracle probably does natively...

Comment: dbms_sql would be my first thought, but if you parse a DDL, it will execute

Comment: You need to know before anyone executes the statement? Or are you getting these from the shared pool?

Comment: I think Justin's suggestion makes the most sense. Eliminate leading whitespace and see what the first word is. If it is WITH, that has to be a select statement. If DECLARE, that's a PL/SQL block. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE are what we'd expect. Just about anything else would be DDL. A whole lot easier than trying to parse it with without executing it and then interrogating v$sql. But of course if you are after SQL already in the shared pool, just use v$sql.command_type, which you can translate using the lookup table sys.audit_actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the explain plan table to get it. Something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_DML_OP(p_SQL IN VarChar2) AS 
BEGIN
    Declare
        mCmd        VarChar2(4000) := 'EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = ''proc_get_dml_op_'' FOR ' || p_SQL;
        mRow        NUMBER(3) := 0;
        CURSOR c IS 
          select PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table', 'proc_get_dml_op_'));
        mExplain    VarChar2(4000);
    Begin
        Begin
            Execute Immediate mCmd;
        Exception
            When OTHERS Then 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OTHER  OR  *** SQLERRM: ' || SQLERRM || ' ***');
                DELETE FROM PLAN_TABLE WHERE STATEMENT_ID = 'proc_get_dml_op_';
        End;
        For r In c LOOP
            mRow := mRow + 1;
            If mRow <= 8 THEN
                mExplain := TRIM(SubStr(r.PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT, InStr(r.PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT, '|', 1, 2) + 1, InStr(r.PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT, '|', 1, 3) - InStr(r.PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT, '|', 1, 2) - 1  ));
                If SubStr(mExplain, 1, 6) IN('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE', 'SELECT', 'MERGE ') THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mExplain);
                    DELETE FROM PLAN_TABLE WHERE STATEMENT_ID = 'proc_get_dml_op_';
                    GoTo EndIt;
                End If;
            End If;
        END LOOP;
        DELETE FROM PLAN_TABLE WHERE STATEMENT_ID = 'proc_get_dml_op_';
      <<EndIt>>
        Null;
    End;
END GET_DML_OP;
```

If you call the procedure with some sql statements ...

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    GET_DML_OP('SELECT * FROM A_TABLE_NAME');
    GET_DML_OP('WITH a AS (Select 1 "NMBR", ''A'' "LTTR" FROM DUAL) Select * From a');
    --
    GET_DML_OP('UPDATE A_TABLE_NAME SET PATH = ''999'' Where PATH Is Null');
    GET_DML_OP('INSERT INTO A_TABLE_NAME VALUES(''xxx'', ''yy'', ''zzz'')');
    GET_DML_OP('DELETE FROM A_TABLE_NAME WHERE PATH Is Null');
    --
    GET_DML_OP('ALTER TABLE A_TABLE_NAME MODIFY(PATH VarChar2(50))');
    GET_DML_OP('MERGE INTO emp e USING dept d ON (e.deptno = d.deptno) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e.COMM = null');
END;
/

R e s u l t :
anonymous block completed
SELECT STATEMENT
SELECT STATEMENT
UPDATE STATEMENT
INSERT STATEMENT
DELETE STATEMENT
OTHER  OR  *** SQLERRM: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement ***
MERGE STATEMENT
```

Comment: @d r - Looks very interesting. Give me time to review this

Answer (score 1):

My open-source program [PLSQL_LEXER](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer) was built to classify SQL statements. Here's a simple example:

```
select statement_classifier.get_command_name('/**/((select * from dual))') command_name
from dual;

COMMAND_NAME
------------
SELECT
```

While this program does not implement a full parser, it uses a lexer built from a finite state machine that is powerful enough to reliably solve this kind of language problem. It can handle all of the thousands of reserved keywords and the many weird language features of SQL and PL/SQL.

The program offers [multiple ways to classify statements](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer/blob/master/packages/statement_classifier.plsql#L85) using the official Oracle names from the documentation or the data dictionary. [Here](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer/blob/master/packages/statement_classifier.plsql#L52) is a more complex example of fully classifying an Oracle statement.

If you're still worried about reliability, the program has several [hundred test cases](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer/blob/master/tests/statement_classifier_test.plsql), and it has successfully classified millions of statements on many production systems. It also works for some undocumented commands, although I do need to upgrade it to include a few new 21c commands

The program has other packages that can be useful if you're trying to create something like your own SQL fiddle. For example, if you're building an interface where users enter commands and the system runs them, [this example](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer#complex-example) shows how to split statements, classify them, prepare them for running, and get the proper feedback message depending on the statement type.